# Does such a function exist always?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Suppose that $f(x)$ is some smooth function on $[0,1]$ with $f(x) \geq c > 0$.  Can we always find a function $g(x)$ smooth satisfying

$g'(x) \not=  0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$
and

$f'(x)g'(x) + 2f(x)g''(x) >0$?

Comment: Firstly, $g$ must be concave up, as if we take $x$ to be such that $f(x)=c$, then $x$ gives the minimum of $f$ on $[0,1]$. Hence, $2cg^{\prime\prime}(x)$ must be greater than zero.

Comment: @SDevalapurkar I don't see exactly why that must be true.  Perhaps $f'(x)g'(x)$ is sufficiently positive enough to cancel a small negative number?

Comment: But at the minimum, since $c>0$, $f^\prime(x)=0$.

Comment: @SDevalapurkar I am confused.  The function $f(x) = x +1 $ has a minimum at $x=0$ for the interval $[0,1]$, but has  derivative $1$  there.

Comment: I guess it's because I forgot to specify that's it's a minimum on $(0,1)$, not $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, so if the minimum occurs at an interior point, we are fine.  I guess that just leaves the other case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x \frac{h(t)}{f(t)}dt$, where we will select $h>0$ later.  Then $g' = \displaystyle \frac {h}{f}$ and $g'' = \displaystyle \frac {fh'-hf'}{f^2}$.  So you get
$$f'g'+2fg'' = f'\frac{h}{f}+2\frac{fh'-hf'}{f} = \frac{2fh'-hf'}{f}$$
For this to be positive, we need $2f h' > h f' \iff \dfrac{h'}{h} > \dfrac{f'}{2f}$.
So let $k> 0$ be an upperbound of $\dfrac{f'}{f}$ (which should exist for smooth $f$) and choose $h(x) = e^{kx}$, and you have  $g(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x \frac{e^{kt}}{f(t)}dt$.